# Logger for script

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can I create logger for script? For example

```
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (value1,value2);
```

and I want to save this script in my log_table:

```
ID | DATE | SCRIPT
```

Comment: What? Do you mean you want to log the INSERT queries in your database?

Comment: There is no technical reason why you can't store a script in a varchar field,   you would have to construct the script as a string, write it to your log table using an INSERT statement and then run via the EXEC command.

Comment: @EatPeanutButter yes, I want to save query if I change database

Comment: What is preventing you from trying this? A script is nothing more than a string. If you want to save it there is no reason you can't.

Comment: @Sean Lange I think you don't understand me, I'm sorry. I just want to execute trigger(?) which can save query when I change database. If I execute: INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (value1,value2); then this query automatically save in my log_table: ID | DATE | SCRIPT

Comment: You want to add auditing in a trigger? That means this has nothing to do with a script right? For auditing in a trigger you simply insert into your audit table.You need to use the values from the inserted and deleted virtual tables.

Comment: Why do you want/need to capture the actual statement that was executed? What benefit does that provide?

Comment: Perhaps you want to look into sql server audit tables? http://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/sql-server-database-auditing-techniques/

Comment: You are right, most likely audit tables are better. Thank you!